# Equinox Bundle import conflict

Tags: osgi, bundle, equinox

1) Bundle A **reexports** package com.X, which it gets from bundle C

---

2) Bundle B exports package com.X

---

3) Now bunlde D has dependency on both A and B.

---

From where will the bundle D get the package com.X from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is why you have 2 bundles defining the same package - this is called split packages and isn't recommended because you can have problems with shadowing.

With `Import-Package` the runtime will pick either bundle A or B to resolve the package dependency and you can't control this directly (you can do various tricks like the Eclipse guys do by setting mandatory properties on the exports).

With `Require-Bundle` you'll end up with a merged `com.X` package, so you'll see the superset of types, but I'm not sure what happens if you have overlapping types.

The simplest thing is to avoid split packages in the first place.

Comment: thanks steven, your answer was helpful. You mentioned : 
"various tricks like the Eclipse guys do by setting mandatory properties on the exports".... Can you tell what are these techniques. Thanks.

Comment: When a bundle exports a package it can optionally specify additional key/value pairs (they can be anything you want).  These additional key/value pairs can be marked as mandatory, so other bundles can only do the Import-Package if they also specify the same key/value pairs.  Some Eclipse bundles use this technique because they have split packages, but I believe this is more a legacy issue and you should avoid it if possible.